# SSRS CountRows with leading zeros

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

At the end of my file I need to include this line

TRYYYYMMDDYYYYMMDD000000000

Here is what I have so far:

="TR"+REPLACE(TODAY(), "/", "")+REPLACE(TODAY(), "/", "")+CountRows().ToString()

How do I add the leading zero's before the CountRows()?  There should be 9 digits total for the row count.

My current record returns 28 rows so it should look like 000000028

TR2013102320131023000000028

Comment: can y ou try... `right(replicate('0',9) + CountRows().ToString(), 9)`

Comment: @gloomy.penguin produced the standard something went wrong SSRS error. =(

Comment: I don't have SSRS installed where I'm at... what was the error?  can you just run `replicate('0',9)` by itself to see if the function exists?  (I edited that comment a few times, btw... sorry.  I kept seeing things wrong with it.  It should be correct now)

Comment: Try.... `right(StrDup('0',9) + CountRows().ToString(), 9)`

Comment: @gloomy.penguin I cannot run replicate('0',9) by itself.

Comment: @gloomy.penguin same with StrDup.

Comment: omg, i'm dumb.  just do `right("0000000000000000000"+ CountRows().ToString(), 9)`

Comment: You are a genius!  Worked thank you. :)

Comment: k im gonna put that as an answer down below...

Comment: You could make your code much less brittle by using `Today().ToString("yyyyMMdd")` instead of 'Today()`. This won't be affected by localization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do it: `right("0000000000000000000"+ CountRows().ToString(), 9)`